# HSQLDB Bulk Load of huge data

Tags: hsqldb

I have a dataset which is 10GB in size, and 500 Millions of rows. It's in CSV file. How I can load this data into table efficiently with minimum time.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

With HSQLDB, it is essential to create the constraints and indexes on the table prior to loading the data.

Commit the data after loading each chunk of a few thousand rows.

If the table is a CACHED (disk based) table, and you can use a large amount of memory for loading the data, then follow the Guide on setting large cache parameters and start the Java process with a large max memory allocation.

It will take a long time proportional to the number of constraints/indexes on the table.

Using a PreparedStatement will speed things up a little but not much.

Comment: Wouldn't it take very long time for insertion as one ny one record?